# Axios post spotify api request return 400

Tags: reactjs

I am using spotify api for a project. Every request I made work fine except this one. I want to be able  to create a new playlist. The `scope` was already checked, it's not the source of the problem. For this I made the following request

```js
axios('https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + ID + '/playlists', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + data.data.access_token,
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            data: {
                name: Name,
                Description: Description
            }
        })
```

when I tried it, I've got  `400 Bad Request - The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The message body will contain more information`

Here's the link for the spotify api references

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/create-playlist/

Comment: what did u get when u console.log(ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your ID is defined. You need to stringify your json.

Been a while since I used axios,

```
axios('https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + ID + '/playlists', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + data.data.access_token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
                name: Name,
                description: Description
            })
        })
```

Comment: My `ID` is correct, and I tried `JSON.stringify`, still got the `error 400`

Comment: try description in small letters, currently it's capital D

Comment: oh my god, it was the `D`...feel so bad. Thank you mate.